# javascript inntertext will not work

Tags: javascript, html

i am not familiar to use javascript.i was used innertext .But browser will not display that contentplease help me any one..

```
<script language="JavaScript">

function Show(name)
{
document.getElementById("name").innerText = name;

}
 </script>

<a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="Show('Jancy');" >
<span id="name"></span>
```

please help me what is wrong in here...?

Comment: Fyi, it's `type="text/javascript"`, not `language="whatever"`

Comment: After you solve this with the answer below, I recommend you to try a debugger like [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/)!!

Comment: @ThiefMaster `type` defaults to `"text/javascript"`, so just `<script>` is fine...

Answer (score 2):

Use `innerHTML`:

```
function Show(name)
{
    document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = name;
}
```

I've also updated your JavaScript to move away from inline JavaScript, based on the following HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#" class="showNames">Jancy</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="showNames">Sarah</a></li>
</ul>
<span id="name"></span>​
```

JavaScript:

```
function Show(name) {
    document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = name;
}

var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

for (var i=0, len=links.length; i<len; i++){
    if (links[i].className == 'showNames'){
        links[i].onclick = function(){
            Show(this.innerHTML);
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/bFdu6/3/).

**Note:** the use of a `ul` and `li` elements is entirely optional, I chose to use those simply for presentational purposes.

JavaScript references, from the Mozilla Developer Network:

- [`className](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.className).
- [`getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementById).
- [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.innerHTML).

Comment: There is an Copy & Waste error in your second example (second line). That said [`node.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.textContent) is more like [`node.innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.textContent#Differences_from_innerText) and a more proper way of [inserting text](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.textContent#Differences_from_innerHTML).

Comment: Thanks, @Saxoier, I hadn't noticed that! =) Edited and fixed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that the anchor element isn't complete.  It needs to be ended with an `</a>` element.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="Show('Jancy');" >click me</a>
<span id="name"></span>​
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vyDcd/1/